# On GET action in jsp to Spring Controller drops the url query string parameters

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller, url-parameters

I am not getting my query string parameters from jsp to Controller.

Below is my uploadSuccess.jsp code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:url var="formActionURL" value="http://localhost:8080/scanpipeline/readQRCode">
<c:param name="fileName" value="${fileName}" />
</c:url>

<form method="GET"  action="${formActionURL}" > 

<h3>
File Uploaded Successfully!
</h3>

<strong>File name is :<%= request.getAttribute("fileName") %> !!</strong> 
<strong>Total number of data read from file: <%=request.getAttribute("filedata") %> !! 
</strong><br>
<p></p> 
If you want to see QR Code information in the upload file, click 'Ok'   <br> 
<input type="submit" value="Ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring Controller method is:
    //http://localhost:8080/pipeline/readQRCode

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/readQRCode",  method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String readQRCode(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "fileName", required = true) String fileName)
{
........................
}
```

The url query string that I see in view source of jsp is:
action="http://localhost:8080/pipeline/readQRCode?fileName=Paper+Scan.pdf" >

However, when I submit the jsp form, it gives me Http Status 400 error "Required String parameter 'fileName' is not present".  It is dropping the query string from ? onward.  Please guide.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i can see from the code you post this part maybe is wrong:

```
<c:url var="formActionURL" value="http://localhost:8080/scanpipeline/readQRCode">
```

Because when you submit you will be redirect to this url, and so you don't have any query string.

Try change with adding a hidden input to your form with value of query string. So being a get method the value of this input will be in your URL as query string.

Like this:

```
<form method="GET"  action="${formActionURL}" > 

<input type="hidden" value=${fileName} />
<h3>
File Uploaded Successfully!
</h3>
```

Last Edit:

In answer to your comment, your original code was incorrect because you was using  tag in a wrong way.

This is the correct form:

```
<c:url value="/index.jsp" var="myURL">
<c:param name="trackingId" value="1234"/>
<c:param name="reportType" value="summary"/>
</c:url>

<form method="GET"  action="<c:import url="${myURL}"/>" >
```

So you can try also this solution applied to your code, of course you need to remove the first solution.

Comment: Thanks @Mike.  I tried it but the output is same.  This time when I did viewsource on browser I got same code:                                                                                                           <form method="GET"  action="http://localhost:8080/scanpipeline/readQRCode?fileName=Paper Scan.pdf" >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Could it be that browser truncating the query string?

Comment: I made some changes in my answer try this new one. And use your old action for the form.

Comment: Thanks @Mike.  It works now with hidden parameters.  I did not understand why the controller method is not invoked when I append parameters to the url string.  Is it wrong way of coding ?

Comment: I can't really understand what are you asking. Can you please give me some more info of what your trying to do? i would be glad to answer you

Comment: I mean to say is that it works with hidden parameter but in case of my original code, it did not work, why?  

New Code: <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="<%= request.getAttribute("fileName")%>" /><c:url var="formActionURL" value="http://localhost:8080/scanpipeline/readQRCode"> </c:url><form method="GET"  action="${formActionURL}" >     

Orignial code: <c:url var="formActionURL" value="http://localhost:8080/scanpipeline/readQRCode"><c:param name="fileName" value="${fileName}" /></c:url><form method="GET"  action="${formActionURL}">

Comment: Thanks.  I tried using your modified code , but it does jsp include ie. this line 
    <c:import url="${myURL}"/> 
    I think the solution is to have hidden field like you suggested previously.

Comment: I think that you have to put <c:import> tag in action of your form to use the URL that you setup with <c:param> tags.